# Laravel/Lumen Eloquent: mutator value used instead of database value when looking up related models

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, lumen, eloquent

I am trying to build an Eloquent `hasMany` relationship between a `Tag` model (which represents an RFID tag containing a MAC address) and a `Message` model which represents a single message from this RFID tag. The `Message` contains a MAC address for the `Tag` that sent it, so therefore the `hasMany` relationship is defined by relating the `Tag`'s MAC address ("mac" field) to the `Message` "tag_mac" field.

The MAC addresses in both tables are stored as an unsigned BIGINT rather than as a string in order to optimise space usage and to improve indexing. The `Tag` model therefore contains a `getMacAttribute()` accessor and `setMacAttribute()` mutator, and the `Message` model contains `getTagMacAttribute()` and `setTagMacAttribute()` equivalents. The accessors convert the BIGINT to a hexadecimal string and the mutators perform the reverse operation ready for storage in the table.

The `hasMany` relationship however does not work correctly; even with models that should be related, the relationship returns no results.  By using `DB::listen()` to log queries, I was able to see that the following SQL statement is being executed when I try to obtain the related `Message` models from a `Tag`: -

```
select * from `messages` where `messages`.`tag_mac` = ? and `messages`.`tag_mac` is not null
```

The value of the binding is: "FA1BD608E9C6", which is of course a hexadecimal string and not a BIGINT.

This shows that the `hasMany` relation is incorrectly using the `Tag`'s "mac" attribute value *after* the accessor, whereas the raw value should instead be used.  Querying the "messages" table for a "tag_mac" value which is a hexadecimal string will of course return no results as the "tag_mac" is stored as an unsigned BIGINT.

Looking at `\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOneOrMany`, line 370 (as of Lumen 5.4), shows that `Model::getAttribute()` is being used to retrieve the value of the local attribute: -

```
return $this->parent->getAttribute($this->localKey);
```

Calling `\App\Tag::find(1)->getAttribute("mac")` indeed returns the hexadecimal string as expected, meaning that the accessor is invoked. However, for a relation which is building a query for the database, the raw attribute value needs to be used instead.

Removing the `getMacAttribute()` accessor from the `Tag` model shows that the generated SQL uses the correct BIGINT value (274997461969350 in this example) in the binding, and indeed all related `Message` models are returned. So the problem is with the accessor, however this is required for other elements of the application. I know that I could append a custom field with a hexadecimal version of the MAC address, however this should not be necessary in my opinion and appears to be a messy workaround.

As an experiment only, replacing line 370 in `\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOneOrMany` with: -

```
return $this->parent->getOriginal($this->localKey);
```

solves this particular problem.

My question is: how do I disable the accessor for this field when performing the `hasMany` relationship query, or have I made a mistake with my implementation?

Comment: I think you've over-explained what you're doing here. Hard to pinpoint what the issue is (a tl;dr version would be "Laravel uses mutator value instead of database value when looking up related models" I think?)

Comment: Yes exactly, thanks.  I have updated the question title accordingly.